# git diff of two drupal 'sites' directories on git hub

Tags: git, github

I am pretty green at git but i need it to compare two separate directories. Is this even possible? I just made a repository and moved stuff up to git hub. I need to do the same from the other directory. If it matters, I'm moving up two separate 'sites' directories from two drupal installs. I need to discover where they diverge. Please let me know if it is possible and if so how.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using git, use [git-diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for it. Provide directory paths as arguments.

Also a drupal module having the same functionality is pending for approval in full project application queue. You may try it but note it may or may not be reliable http://drupal.org/sandbox/stuchl4n3k/1443930